# How to change visibility of the buttons in the others items in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview with the buttons inside of items. When I click one button in one of them I want to hide buttons in others items. I know how to do it in same item where I clicked button, but I no have idea how to do it in other things without touching them. How to do it? I tried with the boolean in the ViewHolder, but it doesn't work.

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

private List<Task> tasks;
private boolean visible;

public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView nameTextView, idTextView;
    private Button travelButton, travellingButton, workButton, stopButton;

    public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
        idTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_text_view);
        travelButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.travel_button);
        travellingButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.travelling_button);
        workButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.work_button);
        stopButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stop_button);

        if (visible == true) {
            travelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            travelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
    return new ListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ListAdapter.ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Task task = tasks.get(position);

    holder.nameTextView.setText(task.getName());
    holder.idTextView.setText(String.valueOf(task.getId()));
    holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.travelButton.setText(R.string.start_travel);
    holder.travellingButton.setText(R.string.travelling);

    holder.travelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.travellingButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.workButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFECB3"));
            visible = true;
        }
    });
    holder.workButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.workButton.setText(R.string.working);
            holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.travellingButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.stopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCDD2"));
        }
    });
    holder.stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.travelButton.setText(R.string.start_travel);
            holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.travellingButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.workButton.setText(R.string.work);
            holder.workButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.stopButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            visible = false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tasks == null ? 0 : tasks.size();
}

public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    this.tasks = tasks;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the answer to my question. I just made an interface that informs activity about the need to refresh the adapter and it works.

ListAdapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

private List<Task> tasks;
private int travelButtonVisibility=-1;
private OnButtonClickListener mOnButtonClickListener;

public void setOnButtonClickListener(OnButtonClickListener onButtonClickListener) {
    mOnButtonClickListener = onButtonClickListener;
}

public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView nameTextView, idTextView;
    private Button travelButton, travellingButton, workButton, stopButton;

    public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
        idTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_text_view);
        travelButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.travel_button);
        travellingButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.travelling_button);
        workButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.work_button);
        stopButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
    return new ListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ListAdapter.ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Task task = tasks.get(position);

    holder.nameTextView.setText(task.getName());
    holder.idTextView.setText(String.valueOf(task.getId()));
    holder.travelButton.setText(R.string.start_travel);
    holder.travellingButton.setText(R.string.travelling);


    if (travelButtonVisibility <= 0) {
        holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if (position == travelButtonVisibility){
        holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.travellingButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.workButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFECB3"));
    }

    holder.travelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mOnButtonClickListener.onTravelButtonClick();
            travelButtonVisibility = position;
            holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
    holder.workButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.workButton.setText(R.string.working);
            holder.travellingButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.stopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCDD2"));
        }
    });
    holder.stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.travelButton.setText(R.string.start_travel);
            holder.travellingButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.workButton.setText(R.string.work);
            holder.workButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.stopButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            travelButtonVisibility = -1;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tasks == null ? 0 : tasks.size();
}

public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    this.tasks = tasks;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public interface OnButtonClickListener {
    void onTravelButtonClick();
}
}
```

MainActvity:

```
private void initList() {
    listAdapter = new ListAdapter();

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    listAdapter.setTasks(tasks);

    listAdapter.setOnButtonClickListener(new ListAdapter.OnButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTravelButtonClick() {
            recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Travel Button");
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to onBindViewHolder:

```
holder.travellingButton.setVisibility(visible? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

and after changing "visible" call

```
notifyItemRangeChanged(0, getItemCount())
```

Comment: Something is wrong. In the first line I switched places Visible and Gone because in your version buttons they were not visible from the beginning. Then I put second line to the buttons clicks and it almost works, but if I click button all buttons disappear again.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private optionSelected = 0

    public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
        idTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_text_view);
        travelButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.travel_button);
        travellingButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.travelling_button);
        workButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.work_button);
        stopButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stop_button);

        if (visible == true) {
            travelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            travelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
    return new ListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ListAdapter.ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Task task = tasks.get(position);

    if(option == 0 && position == 0){
    holder.nameTextView.setText(task.getName());
holder.idTextView.setText(String.valueOf(task.getId()));
    holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.travelButton.setText(R.string.start_travel);
   holder.travellingButton.setText(R.string.travelling);
} else if(option == 1 && position == 1){
   // do Something with your view
} else {
     // do something with your view
}


    holder.travelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            option = 1
            notifyDataChanged()

        }
    });
    holder.workButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            option = 2
            notifyDataChanged()
        }
    });
    holder.stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            option = 3
            notifyDataChanged()
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tasks == null ? 0 : tasks.size();
}

public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    this.tasks = tasks;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: There is same error like in others solutions. Works fine, but it works on item with - 1 lower position. For example: if I click item number 4 it works for item number 3 etc.
I think it's the reason for using notifyDataChanged().

Answer (score 0):

You're setting different visibility depending on which button is clicked. I recommend using an enum instead of a boolean to store the state of your list and update the state on each button click.

Define an enum in your Adapter and create a member variable using it:

```
private List<Task> task;
private ListState state = ListState.showButton1; // Set a default value

// I used "showButton" but this can be any set a values that represent your various states
private enum ListState{
    showButton1, showButton2, showButton3
}
```

Inside of your onBindViewHolder:

```
// Set the state of the view holder
switch(state){
    case showButton1:
        // Set your corresponding visibility changes on your view holder here
        break;
    case showButton2:
        // Set your corresponding visibility changes on your view holder here
        break;
    case showButton3:
        // Set your corresponding visibility changes on your view holder here
        break;
}

// Make sure to update the adapter whenever a button is clicked
holder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // Set the state and notify the adapter
        state = ListState.showButton2;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
})

// Add click listeners for your remaining buttons
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, it will initially display all travellingButton and when you click travellingButton of one of the list item, travellingButton of other items will hide.

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

private List<Task> tasks;
private int travelButtonVisibility=-1; 

public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView nameTextView, idTextView;
    private Button travelButton, travellingButton, workButton, stopButton;

    public ListViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
        idTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id_text_view);
        travelButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.travel_button);
        travellingButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.travelling_button);
        workButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.work_button);
        stopButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.stop_button);


    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
    return new ListViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ListAdapter.ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Task task = tasks.get(position);

    holder.nameTextView.setText(task.getName());
    holder.idTextView.setText(String.valueOf(task.getId()));

    holder.travelButton.setText(R.string.start_travel);
    holder.travellingButton.setText(R.string.travelling);
    if(travelButtonVisibility==-1 || travelButtonVisibility==position){
    {

     holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
     holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.travelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.travellingButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.workButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFECB3"));
            travelButtonVisibility=position
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    holder.workButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.workButton.setText(R.string.working);
            holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.travellingButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.stopButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCDD2"));
        }
    });
    holder.stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.travelButton.setText(R.string.start_travel);
            holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.travellingButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.workButton.setText(R.string.work);
            holder.workButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.stopButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            visible = false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return tasks == null ? 0 : tasks.size();
}

public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    this.tasks = tasks;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work :( I need to refresh the recyclerview so there is need to use notifyDataChanged(). But it works for the item with - 1 smaller number in list. There is some problem with refreshing the recyclerview.

Comment: You need to add notifyDataSetChanged(); method after this line  travelButtonVisibility=position , I have edited my answer, Please check and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Still doesn't work. In this case button is blocked in item where I clicked and works item -1 position lower. So if I clicked item number 5, then this item is blocked and works item number 4. The notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work well.

Comment: please remove below line from travelButtonClick, holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: I did it and it's same. I think your solution is very close, because in first version it works almost fine, but buttons in other items disappear after click stopButton. I need the disappearing buttons after pressing travelButton and all appearing after pressing stopBuuton. It's very close.

Comment: Then why are you using  holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); after every button click?

Comment: Because I want to make this button visible after stopButton. If I click travelButton I want to hide travelButtons in other items to prevent them from clicking. So stopButton is a restarter for recyclerview. It unlocks buttons of other items.

Comment: Ok then remove holder.travelButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); from other button click and add
travelButtonVisibility=-1
 notifyDataSetChanged();
in stop button click